I always get a GetCredentialException "activity is cancelled by the user" when I click the sign in button
I tried to use Google One Tap login using Firebase Authentication, but when credential selection dialog show up and I choose one of my account, I didn't get to login, the credential selection dialog closed and I got this GetCredentialException message:
activity is cancelled by the user.
The error message keep showing that, I didn't click anything that caused the credential selection dialog closed, but it's keep self closing
I tried to modified my code and I still got that GetCredentialException message, but when I create new project and I tried make new Google One Tap login, it works
Here is my LoginActivity:
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        auth = Firebase.auth

        showLoading(false)

        binding.googleLogin.setOnClickListener {
            showLoading(true)
            signIn()
        }

        ...
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this) //import from androidx.CredentialManager

        val googleIdOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(BuildConfig.WEB_CLIENT_ID)
            .build()

        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder() //import from androidx.CredentialManager
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val result: GetCredentialResponse = credentialManager.getCredential( //import from androidx.CredentialManager
                    request = request,
                    context = this@LoginActivity,
                )
                handleSignIn(result)
            } catch (e: GetCredentialException) { //import from androidx.CredentialManager
                Log.d("Error", e.message.toString())
            }
        }
        showLoading(false)
    }

    private fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
        // Handle the successfully returned credential.
        when (val credential = result.credential) {
            is CustomCredential -> {
                if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
                    // Process Login dengan Firebase Auth
                    try {
                        val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)
                        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(googleIdTokenCredential.idToken)
                    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Catch any unrecognized custom credential type here.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
                }
            }
            else -> {
                // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
                Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential: AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user: FirebaseUser? = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (currentUser != null) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "LoginActivity"
    }

    private fun showLoading(isVisible: Boolean) {
        binding.progressBar.visibility = if (isVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}


Did you ever get this to work?

Please check your Credentials on your Cloud Console.
Inside OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, make sure you have the Web Client Id. If not, create the new client id. Thus, use the web client id, not the android one.
You can see the reference here:
https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg
